# C# DateTime in nanoseconds vs UTC and local

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timestamp

I have the following value in my database: 637406344505540000 which represents the time in UTC.

When I run this line of code.

```
return new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Local); // it returns 11/10/2020 7:47:30 PM
```

I tried to set the Kind to UTC it returns the same.

This is the result of my execution in Immediate Window of Visual studio

```
new DateTime(637406344505540000, DateTimeKind.Local);
{11/10/2020 7:47:30 PM}
    Date: {11/10/2020 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 10
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 315
    Hour: 19
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 554
    Minute: 47
    Month: 11
    Second: 30
    Ticks: 637406344505540000
    TimeOfDay: {19:47:30.5540000}
    Year: 2020

new DateTime(637406344505540000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
{11/10/2020 7:47:30 PM}
    Date: {11/10/2020 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 10
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 315
    Hour: 19
    Kind: Utc
    Millisecond: 554
    Minute: 47
    Month: 11
    Second: 30
    Ticks: 637406344505540000
    TimeOfDay: {19:47:30.5540000}
    Year: 2020
```

In my opinion, for Kind local, it should return the following:
Tue Nov 10 2020 14:47:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

There is a web tool that helped me understand that my value is correct.

https://grammarofdev.blogspot.com/2017/02/c-ticks-to-datetime.html

It shows the local and UTC values corresponding to the ticks in my database.

Is there anything that I am not doing correctly?

Comment: Try `new DateTime(637406344505540000, DateTimeKind.Local).ToString("o")` and you'll see the difference between Local and Utc.

Comment: If you lie to `DateTime` about whether the value is UTC or local, then you get incorrect results. Since the value is stored as UTC, you need to deserialize it the same way. Use `ToLocalTime()` to convert to local time. See duplicate. Better yet, stop using `DateTime`, and use `DateTimeOffset` instead, which has better built-in handling of time zones. Or use Noda (a third party date/time library).

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTimeKind` passed in the constructor is only used to assign the `Kind` property.  It doesn't change the wall time represented by the `Ticks`.

Since your value is stored in terms of UTC, then first create your `DateTime` with UTC kind, then convert it to local time if that's what you need.

```cs
DateTime dt = new DateTime(637406344505540000, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Aside - I'm not sure which database you are using, but most databases have native types for dates and times that will work better than storing them as ticks.